# Python program that takes in a Name and 10 Scores and Returns the Name and 6 highest Scores

Tags: python

```
name = input("Enter name: ")  
scores = input("Enter 10 test scores separated by commas: ")  
data = zip (name, scores)
for (student, score) in zip(names, scores): pass


print(name)  
print(scores)
```

Input name prompt comes up and I enter name and then name is undefined?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\CIS   129\vandress_m8assignment\vandress_m8.py", line 4, in <module>  
    for (student, score) in zip(names, scores): pass  
NameError: name 'names' is not defined. Did you mean: 'name'?
```

Comment: I'm just trying to get the user inputs to be assigned to variables. Then I'll worry about removing the 4 lowest scores.

Comment: Could you please better explain your question and format/indent your code correctly

Comment: A `for` loop with no body will cause an error. If you wish to temporarily have it empty then add the `pass` keyword to its body:
`for (student, score) in zip(names, scores): pass`

Comment: All of it, please see this post on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you read the error message you can see that you do not have a variable called"names". It is even telling you that you might want to use the variable "name".

Comment: Newbie here ty for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient way to achieve this would be with the following code:

```py
import heapq

def Top6TestScoresOutof10():  
    name = input("Enter name: ")  
    data = input("Enter 10 test scores separated by commas: ")  
    scores = [int(score) for score in data.split()]
    heapq.heapify(scores)
    return name, heapq.nlargest(6, scores)
    

name, scores = Top6TestScoresOutof10()  
print(name)  
print(scores)
```

There's a bit going on here, so I'll explain it line by line. Let's start with the
`scores = [int(score) for score in data.split()]` line. First you'll want to understand [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp). This is the process of building a list in place using the syntax `[x for x in some_iterable]`. Next, the `data.split()` will covert the string supplied by the user by whitespace, so `"a    b c  d      e           food"` becomes `['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e', 'food']`. And `int(score)` performs type casting on the string, to convert it from a string to an integer. so if we enter `45 24  20   48   100`, `scores` will be equal to a list of integers, `[45, 24, 20, 48, 100]`. Having these numbers as integers is important, since one of your requirements is that you want to collect the top 6.

After this, we're using the python `heapq` library, which "provides an implementation of the heap queue algorithm". Heaps are an extremely powerful data structure for problems just like this one, I would definitely recommend reading up on them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). With the `heapq.heapify(scores)` line, we're performing an inline, linear time transformation of our list into a heap. This allows us to quickly pick the nlargest values from our list. Thus, on the next line, we return the `name` and `heapq.nlargest(6, scores)`.

Comment: thank you for that very much. When I email my distance learning instructor its 3 days before they basically just say figure it out. TYTYTY!!!

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: had to separate by spaces instead of commas. Clearly answered and gave me some awesome info about heapq library!